# Rigorous definition of the derivative of $f\left(x,p\left(x\right)\right)$

Tags: derivatives

If we have $f\left(x\right)$ $x$ real and $f$ a real function. The rigorous definition of the derivative of the function is 
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}
$$
**My question is**
If we have $f(x,p(x))$, where $f$ and $p$ real functions, $f$ is an unknown function. What is the rigorous derivative of $f$ with respect $x$?

Comment: Make you question more clear....

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for such a definition since the expression you mention can be computed in the framework of the theory of functions of several real variables.

First of all, note that $f$ depends on two arguments, let us call them $x$ and $y$, so we speak of the function $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$. Having two arguments, $f$ admits a *partial derivative* with respect to each of them; we call them $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}$ respectively. Also, note that the "chain rule" will apply here in the second argument, since $f$ depends on $y$ and this one, in turn, depends on $x$ (through $p$). Therefore, the derivative with respect to $x$ of $f(x,p(x))$ is $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} p'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a function
$$
g(x)=f(x,p(x))
$$
and its derivative at $x$ is (provided the limit exists)
$$
g'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,p(x+h))-f(x,p(x))}{h}
$$

If, for a given $x$, you know that $f$ is differentiable at $(x,p(x))$ and $p$ is differentiable at $x$, then
$$
g'(x)=D_1(f)(x,p(x))+D_2(f)(x,p(x))p'(x)
$$
where $D_1(f)$ and $D_2(f)$ denote the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the first and second variable. The assumption about differentiability can be relaxed, though, but finding necessary and sufficient conditions would be quite difficult.